# Puma silent crash with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, puma

I have a puma server running a ruby on rails app on an AWS EC2 instance. It was working fine for a while, but I found it responding with 502 errors a few hours later. The app is deployed with capistrano.

A simple restart of puma fixed the problem temporarily, but I want to prevent it happening again. Not quite sure what to try first.

Here's my capistrano puma config:

```
set :puma_rackup, -> { File.join(current_path, 'config.ru') }
set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"
set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/puma.rb"
set :puma_access_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :puma_role, :app
set :puma_env, fetch(:rack_env, fetch(:rails_env, 'production'))
set :puma_threads, [0, 8]
set :puma_workers, 0
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true
set :puma_preload_app, false
set :bundle_gemfile, -> { release_path.join('Gemfile') }
```

Puma error log doesn't show any crashes.

Nginx error log shows (xx'd out client ip):
2016/08/09 06:25:52 [error] 1081#0: *348 connect() to unix:///home/deploy/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: example.com, request: "POST /mypath HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///home/deploy/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock:/mypath", host: "example.com"

Comment: Are you running out of open files limit? (network connection is a file too) What `ls /proc/<pid of your puma worker>/fd | wc -l` and `cat /proc/<same pid>/limits` shows?

Comment: @Vasfed `ls /proc/2522/fd | wc -l` > 15 `cat /proc/2522/limits` > Max open files            1024                 4096                 files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1045).

> Ok, thanks for the config. That all looks fine so my guess is you're getting a process crash due to a bad extension. Since you're in production, I'd suggest uncommenting the workers line and using at least 2 workers. That will at least shield you from the crashes a little because the other worker will be able to handle traffic while the crashed one is automatically restarted.

Comment: Hello, I am experiencing the same problem since I edited my puma.rb file after installing foreman. I am trying to find a solution. I have already two workers running.

Comment: I'm no expert but perhaps take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1224)? If yours is different I'd recommend opening a new issue on GitHub, perhaps referencing the issue in my answer above. The puma guys are pretty quick to respond.